# Private Message Facebook Page using Facebook iOS SDK?

Tags: objective-c, ios, facebook, private-messaging

I'm developing an iOS App and I want to have users log into my App using the Facebook SDK and then privately message a Facebook Page I've created. My App logs into Facebook fine and I can get a user to post onto their own walls, but I want to have the user privately message my Facebook Page? Any ideas on how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You cant send him a private message using iOS Facebook SDK, but you can send him a App Request, It will shown in the AppCenter of the User, Following code will help you

```
Facebook * fbReq = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:@"xxxxxxxxxxxxxx" andDelegate:self];


NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               @"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", @"title",
                               @"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",  @"message", 
                               @"xxxxxxxxxxx", @"to",
                               nil];  

[fbReq dialog:@"apprequests" andParams:params andDelegate:self];
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I don't believe that will work with what I have in mind. No worries mate, I've got another idea to achieve what I want. Cheers.

Comment: hey can you post your answer.